# Why are my grid-spans getting extra margins?

Tags: sass, singularitygs

Using the Singularity Grid System:

I have a nested grid. Nothing fancy, just 2 column. Code is like this:

```
main-content { @include grid-span(8,1); }
sidebar { @include grid-span(4,9); }
```

It renders fine, but I keep getting undesired margins. The main content has a small margin-left and the sidebar has a small margin-right. I want these to have zero margins on the edge, similar to declaring main-content as "alpha" and sidebar as "omega."

Here is the CSS (at full desktop width):

```
main-content { width: 65%;float: left;margin-right: -100%;margin-left: 0.83333%;clear: none;}
sidebar-first {width: 31.66667%;float: right;margin-left: 0;margin-right: 0.83333%;clear:none;}
```

I didn't think this was default Singularity behavior, to add those small margins on the outer edges of my grid. Or is it? Can I get around it somehow? (besides just manually adding margin-left:0 and margin-right:0). Of course if there's margin on the outer edges, the total width of each DIV should increase as well (e.g. - for the main-content, instead of 65%, it'd be 65.83333)

Comment: Can you recreate this on http://sassmeister.com/? Remember to change your version of Sass to 3.2.14 from the settings (gear icon).

Comment: Thanks for reading. I did try to recreate the page on sassmeister.com, but it seems to be ok there. My page is http://sassmeister.com/gist/9420745 --- I have a copy of my page here where it's not working, http://webdesignminnesota.com/test.htm --- same versions of breakpoint, sass, and singularity. I'll keep plugging away at this but if anything comes to mind, please let me know. It just seems as though my grid-spans are being generated with this extra margin on the outside, and not anything in my CSS.

Comment: Looks like I'm running compass 0.12.3, which is one newer than the version on sassmeister.

Comment: A patch version like that won't make a difference. It being correct on SassMeister tells me that it's something with your setup. Are you running everything through Bundler as per the [installation instructions](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki/Installation#wiki-installation)

Comment: I do use Bundler, yes. I don't know if this makes any sense, but I think I'm close to resolving the issue. I was using a bunch of custom layouts, and each layout was a partial (e.g. - _threecolgrid.layout.scss). I thought I could have a few less CSS files by using partials for everything? But once I changed my custom layouts files to NOT be partials, and generate their own CSS, the values were suddenly correct (no extra margins). I don't know if I've uncovered a bug, or just confused, but that's what I've found so far.

Comment: Consider sharing your progress, @minneapolisdan.

Comment: No progress, sorry. I don't use partials for my layout sass, and don't have trouble. As to WHY that is, I'm hoping someone else can enlighten me.